# PhantomJS: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(TimeoutError)

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, phantomjs, browser-automation

I have issues with phantomjs not connecting to websites, as it is showed in those debugs logs :

```
Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(TimeoutError) ( "Socket operation timed out" ) URL: "https://google.com/"
```

The code is just as simple as this, normally taking a screenshot once the website is logged.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg);
};
page.open('https://google.com/');
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    console.log('super launch');
    page.render('google.png');
    console.log('super end');
    phantom.exit();
}
```

However, the screenshot is not taken, and it is evident PhantomJS did not connect to https://google.com

Same for the screenshot taking code from documentation :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Will output :

```
Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(TimeoutError) ( "Socket operation timed out" ) URL: "http://github.com/"
```

One is HTTPS, one is HTTP, none work.

I have enabled PhantomJS in the firewall too.

I tried the test suite, colorwheel.js worked just fine (evaluate scripts + synthetizing an image on a created page) but technews.js does not exist in example\

And I tried also to use --ignore-ssl-errors=true and --ssl-protocol=tlsv1, as well as --ssl-protocol=any, nothing changed anything.

What is going on?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ok I'll try to update

Comment: Updated! 
I think the most important part are to debug :
`2016-07-11T20:00:53 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(TimeoutError) ( "Socket operation timed out" ) URL: "http://lordsandknights.com/"` and
`2016-07-11T20:00:53 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(Invalid)`

Comment: @JohnDoe, please edit your post so there is a clear question in it, currently it is unclear what you're asking. Remember that Stackoverflow is not Upwork or RentACoder and try to do as much as you can yourself, try to investigate things you don't know or understand with Google prior to posting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer to the question, with difficulty but that can be interesting.

Path must be ISO 32 (I believe), and I had a parent folder which contained a non ISO 32 character. Just moving this to a completely compatible path made the script working.

Morality : english everywhere ;)